# How to show that this sequence is not a Cauchy sequence in $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

In my lecture notes, it was mentioned that the following function:

Define
$$f_{a}(x):=
\begin{cases}
      0 & \text{for}\quad  |x-x_0|>a \\
      \dfrac{1}{2a} &  \text{for}\quad   |x-x_0|<a
\end{cases} 
$$

One can show that ${f_{1/n}}$ is not a Cauchy sequence in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

What I did:
Let $||\cdot ||$ denote the $L^1$ norm.
Given the Integral
$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{1/n}(x)$, we know that f is non zero only in $|x-x_0|<\frac{1}{n}$. Writing $|x-x_0|<\frac{1}{n}$ as an Interval gives us $(x_0-1/n,x_0+1/n)$ thus we can write

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{1/n}(x)dx=\int_{x_0-1/n}^{x_o+1/n}f_{1/n}(x)dx=\int_{x_0-1/n}^{x_o+1/n}\frac{n}{2}dx=1$$

$||f_{1/n}(x)-f_{1/m}(x)||=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{1/n}(x)-f_{1/m}(x) dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{1/n}(x) dx -\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{1/m}(x) dx=1-1=0$

This would mean it is a Cauchy Sequence. Which should not be possible according to the Text at the beginning.
I am a little bit confused right now.

Comment: For your definition of $f_{1/n}$ to make sense, you need to say what $a$ is. I would expect $a=1/n$. But then, later in your calculation, you'd have different $a$'s for $n$ and for $m$.

Comment: What is $a$ in the definition of $f_{1/n}$?

Comment: @AndreasBlass I edited it

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I edited It

Comment: Where you wrote "The relevant case is $|x-x_0|<a$," that $a$ needs to be both $1/n$ and $1/m$ in the subsequent computation.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I edited it again, but now I get the exact opposite of what I wanted to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in calculating the norm
$\|f_{1/n}-f_{1/m}\|$.

If we consider $m>n$, then

$$\|f_{1/n}-f_{1/m}\|=\int_{x_0-1/n}^{x_0-1/m}\frac{n}{2}dx+\int_{x_0-1/m}^{x_0+1/m}\frac{m}{2}-\frac{n}{2}dx+\int_{x_0+1/m}^{x_0+1/n}\frac{n}{2}dx=2-\frac{2n}{m}.$$

Hence, in order to prove that $(f_{1/n})$ is not a Cauchy sequence, we need to prove that:

$$\exists \varepsilon>0,\ \forall k\in \mathbb{N}, \text{ such that } \exists \ m,n>k \text{ and } \|f_{1/m}-f_{1/n}\|>\varepsilon.$$

Take $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. Then, for any $k>0$, take some $n>k$ and $m=2n$. Therefore,
$$\|f_{1/m}-f_{1/n}\|=1>\varepsilon.$$